# How can I run MiniTest tests before running normal code in the file?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I want to change my following code

```
load "API.rb"
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Test < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  MiniTest::Assertions.diff = nil
  def setup
  end

  def test_character_detection
    assert_equal "Gandalf", Story.get_first_character(2717)
  end
end

puts "TEST"
```

so tests will run before normal code (in this case - 'puts "TEST"').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late answer. Minitests are artful.

`minitest/autorun` uses [at_exit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit) method. It executes the given block when interpreter's work almost done. Roughly speaking "at the end" of your program's lifetime. Though you can call `at_exit` method more than once and blocks will execute in LIFO order.

---

More interesting details about `at_exit` and its usage you can find [here](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/06/are-we-abusing-at-exit/).

Also you may look at minitests [source code](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest.rb). (in this file `at_exit` called)

Good luck!